# Access to the element of a header Template in a grouped gridView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

For a windows 8 application in C#/XAML, I would like to be able to know the position (X and Y) of a button that I have in the header template of a grouped grid View:

Here is the simple Xaml Code :

```
 <GridView  x:Name="PicturesGridView" SelectionMode="None"     
 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs1}}" IsItemClickEnabled="True"
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomTileItem}" ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"  IsSwipeEnabled="True"> 

            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </local:MyGridView.ItemsPanel>
        <local:MyGridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle x:Name="MyGroupStyle">
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="MyDataTemplate">
                        <Button x:Name="HeaderButton" Click="Button_Click_1" Content="{Binding Key}" Foreground="Black" Background="White" FontSize="30" Margin="0,0,0,-10" ></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
  <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemWidth="75" ItemHeight="150" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
    <GridView>
```

I succeed in accessing to the Button inside the header template by doing this :

```
            var template = element.FindName("PicturesGridView") as MyGridView;
            var group = template.GroupStyle[0] as GroupStyle;
            var buttonHeader = group.HeaderTemplate.LoadContent() as Button;
```

But then I can't distinguish each button of my template. I would like an array of physical button representing my data and their position.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WinRT Tookit has what you need...Check out http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/downloads/get/467926 and look at the VisualTreeHelperExtensions.

Using the extension method  GetDescendantsOfType you can write code like the following:

var buttons = PicturesGridView.GetDescendantsOfType().ToArray();

Now, this will give you all the buttons in PicturesGridView, so if you have item templates that also contain buttons, you will get those as well.  You could set the Tag property on the button in the Header template so you could easily identify them from other buttons.